# Problem in xml domit parser

Tags: php, xml

Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in /var/www/html/domit/xml_domit_parser.php on line 3302
in line no.3302 $xmlText = eregi_replace('>' . "[[:space:]]+" . '<' , '><', $xmlText);
any one help me to fix this to preg_replace function

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
<?php
$xmlText = preg_replace("/>\s*</", '><', $xmlText);
?>
```

`\s*` matches any number of spaces between a closing and a opening tag.